# Apache 2 start Wordpress instead of standard file

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache2

## how to startup to wordpress instead of standard apache 2 file

I'm a complete noob when it comes to webdevelopment. I decided to find out how it worked a bit.

I created an apache 2 server on my raspberry pi model 3b plus. I installed a mysql database, and installed wordpress under /var/www/html/wordpress. I did it all according to [this tutorial](http://journaldev.com/24954/install-wordpress-on-ubuntu) online. Only gave my database a different name and so on.

The only thing missing in the tutorial is how to now let my ipadress point to wordpress instead of index.html. My plan is to host a very simple wordpress site on my raspberry pi. And let my domainname point to the ip of the raspberry through a portforward on my router. So I need to start wordpress on the raspberry instead of the standard apache 2 files. Just to clarify extra: when I enter the Rpi adress into my browser now, it directs me to the "it works!" index.html file from apache2. I want it to go to the wordpress site I created when I enter the Rpi's ip adress. So I can go to my DNS host and let the domain name I own point to the outside IP adress of my router with a port, which I then redirect to the pi. I.E. host my own little website for fun.

I looked for the answer on the internet but couldn't really find an answer that explained this. The whole server thing, and hosting your own websites is still a bit vaque to me. As I said, never worked with it before. Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: What happens when you hit `http://10.11.12.13/` with your browser, where `10.11.12.13` is the local IP address of your RPi?  Please [edit] your question to explain in more detail.

Comment: I get the index.html with the "it works!" stuff from apache. But i want it to point it to the wordpress that I edited. I'll try and edit my question

Answer (score 2):

There's a small mistake in the tutorial you followed.

To get things to work so hitting `http://203.0.113.114/` where `203.0.113.114` is your machine's local IP address, you must install WordPress in your web server's root directory. The tutorial suggests you install it so you can hit `http://203.0.113.114/wordpress` to get it. That's not what you want.

The tutorial says to do this.

```
cp -R wordpress /var/www/html/
```

Instead you want to do this.

```
cp -R wordpress/* /var/www/html
```

That puts WordPress's files in `/var/www/html/`, not `/var/www/html/wordpress/`.  After you do this, you should be able to say `ls -al /var/www/html` and see a bunch of files, including among others `index.php`.

Once you've done that, do the permission-changing stuff in your tutorial again. Then use your web browser to hit

```
https://10.11.12.13/
```

and you should get WordPress's setup wizard on your browser. [Here are WordPress's own instructions](https://wordpress.org/support/article/how-to-install-wordpress/).

Here's the thing to keep in mind: apache exposes a subset of your machine's file system to web browsers. That subset is rooted at the directory `/var/www/html/`.  And also, when you have php installed, apache interprets files like `foobar.php` not as text, but as php programs. It runs them instead of just sending them to the browser. It's worth your trouble to wrap your brain around these concepts; they're the heart of web server technology.

Again, use your own IP address in place of `203.0.113.114`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm gonna start trying again today or tommorow. Will get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can create virtual host and access site from subdomain for example.

1. create host file
   `/etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress.com.conf`
2. enter

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/wordpress/"
       ServerName wp.localhost
    </VirtualHost>
```

3. Then enable host with command `sudo a2ensite wordpress.com`
4. Then you should be able to access wordpress on subdomain wp.localhost / wp.{yourserveraddress}

Comment: More examples: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: Thank you very much. Will start trying today or tommorow!

Answer (score 1):

## Solved

I found the answer with both of the answers from O.jones and Koxo.

I created a new .conf file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` called something.com.conf (just to test).

entered this bit of code in there:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/wordpress/"
    ServerName something.com
</VirtualHost>
```

After that I did `a2dissite 000-default.conf` to turn the "old" config off. This is the config that directs you to index.html. Then I did `a2ensite something.com` which enables the website on the apache server. After that I did: `sudo service apache2 restart` to restart the service and everything worked.

Thank you O.Jones and Koxo for the help!